# Cannot create a linked server for Sage Line 50 to SQL Server using the 64 bit driver for Sage

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, sage-line-50

I have a Sql Server 2019 Express database to which i want to create a linked server to Sage Line 50.

Now i have installed the 64 bit ODBC driver for Sage Line 50 (see attached Screenshot) and then proceeded to set up the linked server (see screenshot)

Now i put credentials in but get the following error message

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SAGELINE50REPORTS".
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SAGELINE50REPORTS" returned message "The driver returned invalid (or failed to return) SQL_DRIVER_ODBC_VER: 27.2]".
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SAGELINE50REPORTS" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed".
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SAGELINE50REPORTS" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed".
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SAGELINE50REPORTS" returned message "Cannot find all files in data path". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)

what am i doing wrong here?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Haven't you [already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72968354/how-to-setup-linked-server-from-sql-server-express-2019-to-sage-line-50) this?

Comment: Does the `\\jupiter\G_drive\Sage\Line50\ACCDATA` folder exist? The SQL Server service is executed by a Windows account that is not your own - does that account have the necessary Share and file system permissions granted to it?

Comment: Yes the share exists and we had set up a SQL Server service account to have read/write permissions on the folder